# Laravel Queue Worker on Amazon EC2 setup issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, supervisord

I have deployed a Laravel project on EC2 instance. I am using the database queue driver to process my queued jobs.
I have followed the guide below to configure supervisor:
https://gist.github.com/vrajroham/6565c4b2e9b4db693c1524394545a610

However when I try to run laravel worker with the command

```
/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

I get the following response:

```
laravel-worker: ERROR (no such group)
```

below is my conf file (laravel-worker.conf):

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/api/artisan queue:work --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ec2-user
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/api/storage/worker.log
```

I browsed for similar issues but could not resolve the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by superviserd not reading your config. Try to reload supervisord.

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo service supervisord reload
```

What I usually do on kubernetes is creating a single config file for supervisord with. Whenever my worker containers start the following script runs:

```
    echo "Creating config files..."
    rm /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf && \
    dd of=/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf << EOF
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/dev/stdout ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
user=root                ;

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /code/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
EOF

    echo "Starting queue..."
    exec /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: when i execute: "sudo service supervisord reload" command i get "supervisord: unrecognized service"

Comment: @Chamindar2002 Is supervisord installed?  If it is not installed you can run `sudo apt-get install supervisor` on Ubuntu. If it is installed, You might need to run `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/supervisord` to make it executable, but I doubt this is the issue. And maybe run `sudo supervisorctl reread` to read new configs and then `sudo service supervisord reload.

Comment: @ llyas Deckers I installed supervisor with the command `$ easy_install supervisor`. And when i run `supervisorctl reread` i get the following message: _**No config updates to processes**_

Comment: Take a look at this thread -> https://serverfault.com/questions/211525/supervisor-not-loading-new-configuration-files